# pass data table between client server application TCP C#

Tags: c#, rmi, remoting

I have a client server application. It uses the LAN network (TCP).
I wont pass data table client to server and server to client.
Using Remote methods and events (TCP)in C#.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize your DataTable to Xml and send it over the TCP. If you want to be secured, encrypt the bytes.

Best Solution for this would be using WCF with TCP Binding.